# Asymptotic Relationship from Limit

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

F(n) = n-100
G(n) = n-200

I am trying to show the asymptotic relationship between these two functions using limits.

I take the limit n->∞ f(n) / g(n) and I get the result 1 which is constant c.

**From the Big O theorem,**

[image]

**From the Big Omege theorem,**

[image]

My question is: How I supposed to determine whether they are **f = O(g(n)) or f = Ω(g(n))**

In general, what is a good way to find the relationship between given two functions?

Comment: Your theorems are wrong. I suggest ignoring them.

Comment: What theorem is wrong? The one in pictures? They are from following books: Algorithms 2006 S. Dasgupta, C. H. Papadimitriou, and U. V. Vazirani

Comment: The two theorems you quote are unfortunately wrong.

Comment: Could you please answer why they are wrong? Or what is a good way to find the relationship between given two functions?

Comment: There is a counterexample in my answer.

Comment: Note that in your case, both $f = O(g)$ and $f = \Omega(g)$ hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorems you quote are unfortunately wrong. As an example, $2 + \sin n = \Theta(1)$ although the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\sin n}{1}$ doesn't exist.

Here are some theorems which do hold.

**Theorem 1.** Let $f,g$ be two functions such that $f(n),g(n)$ are eventually positive. If the limit $c := \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n)$ exists then

1. $f(n) = O(g(n))$ iff $0 \leq c < \infty$.
2. $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ iff $0 < c \leq \infty$.
3. $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ iff $0 < c < \infty$.
4. $f(n) = o(g(n))$ iff $c = 0$.
5. $f(n) = \omega(g(n))$ iff $c = \infty$.

**Theorem 2.** If $f,g$ are two polynomials which are eventually positive, then the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n)$ exists.

**Theorem 3.** Let $f,g$ be two functions such that $f(n),g(n)$ are eventually positive. Then

1. $f(n) = O(g(n))$ iff $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty$.
2. $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ iff $\lim\inf_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} > 0$.
3. $f(n) = o(g(n))$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$.
4. $f(n) = \omega(g(n))$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \infty$.

Comment: So, according to your theorem, the answer of my question where f(n) is n-100, g(n) is n-200, is f(n)=Ω(g(n)). However, the answer is f(n) = O(g(n)) because both function is O(n).

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: Can we also assume it is (n)=Θ(g(n)) ?

Comment: This is also correct. In fact, $f = \Theta(g)$ iff $f = O(g)$ and $f = \Omega(g)$.

Comment: It's clear now. Thank you!